Extend a div outside the table
Using tailwind, I have a div with class set to "overflow-auto", and a table as its child. How can I make it so that the absolute div inside one of its cells extend beyond the overflowing div?
For context, I'm trying to build a custom dropdown in a cell, and I want to see it go outside the div, but it's getting cut off understandably because of the parent div

Please show the relevant HTML and CSS so far otherwise any answer will be just a guess.
